# Why does my R Markdown file not output a citation from Bib

Tags: r, r-markdown, bibtex

I am using `R Markdown` to create a document with citations. But the citation doesn't reflect on the pdf document generated. Using `RStudio Version 0.98.994` and `R 3.1`

This is the `.rmd` file

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "keniajin"
date: "Tuesday, October 14, 2014"
output: pdf_document
---

This is an R Markdown document. 

```{r}
require(knitcitations)
summary(cars)
bib <- read.bibtex("ieetutorial.bib")
```

You can also embed citations, for example:
Smith says blah [-@author00]
````

The `BibTeX` file is

```
@Book{author00,
  author =   {Author},
  title =    {Title},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  year =     2000}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the last line of your rmd-file to

```
Smith says blah `r citep(bib[["author00"]])`
```